# Reset select box isotope combination on reset button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I've multiple select box filters to filter data using jQuery isotope. I want to reset all the combinations on a button click.
I've tried the following code to reset this; but it only shows all the data and actually not resetting the filter options;

```
$('.reset').on('click', 'button', function () {
    $('.grid').isotope({
        filter: '*',
    });
});
```

I am using following code for the select box filter working;

```
var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.element-item',
    layoutMode: 'vertical'
});
var filters = {};

// filter buttons
$('.filters-button-group').on('change', 'select.filterfields', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var group = $this.attr('data-filter-group');
    filters[ group ] = $this.find(':selected').attr('data-filter');
    var isoFilters = [];
    for ( var prop in filters ) {
      isoFilters.push( filters[ prop ] )
    }
    var selector = isoFilters.join('');
    $('.grid').isotope({ filter: selector });
    return false;
});
```

Please help me to reset all the combination filters on a button click.

Comment: could you replicate the same on jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Please see this: http://jsfiddle.net/arunc43/kfk4jzkL/2/
At the same time time I want to reset the select box value to "All".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `grid` is linked to the `dropdowns` in your script but not vice versa, hence when you reset the grid filter the `dropdowns` are not reset.

you can reset the `dropdowns` explicitly by setting them to `*`.

**JS CODE:**

```
 // filter buttons
 $('.filters-button-group').on('change', 'select.filterfields', function () {
    $('.informativeSection').hide();
    var isoFilters = [];
    $('.option-set').each(function () {
        var filter = $(this).val();
        if (filter !== '*') {
            isoFilters.push($(this).find(':selected').attr('data-filter'));
        }
    });
    var selector = isoFilters.join('');
    console.log('selector:' + selector);
    $('.grid').isotope({
        filter: selector
    });
    //show no documents message
    if ($('.grid').data('isotope').filteredItems.length === 0) { $('.informativeSection').show(); }
    return false;
});

$('.reset').on('click', 'button', function () {
  $('.grid').isotope({ 
    filter: '*',
  });
  //reset the dropdowns explicitly
  $('.option-set').val('*');
});
```

*Edits:*

1. I have updated the filtered logic as well to accommodate reset functionality.
2. Added a informative message when no documents found for given filter.

**Live Demo @ JSFiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/kfk4jzkL/8/**

Comment: Hi...Still the values not resetting. The values are preselected in the "isoFilters" array, so that after click on the "Reset" button the values are retained. Still it displayed all the options but the filter not resetting.

Comment: I have updated the filtered logic as it was too complicated what you had coded.

Comment: Thank you very much...Its working as expected !! One more small doubt; is it possible to display a text "No documents" if there is no combination for filters?. In our example "Black - Medium" combination contains no files and need to display the text "No documents".

Comment: well that should not be problem, as per the isotope community on `https://github.com/metafizzy/isotope/issues/93` there is a way to identify empty records after filter.

Comment: before we discuss on any more requirement lets close this question first and create a new one with addtional requirements/issues. because cluttering to many things in comments will not help others, who might have a similar issue.

Comment: Sure. I'll do so in future. Thank you very much...:)